# Sending Email using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help me with sending an email via google scripts?

Here the challenge I am facing is that the range of the first column (email) may go up to 1000 lists of the email addresses. Although, now it's working fine (for now) how can I make it a dynamic range of list to be fed over my email lists to the script.

Code:

```js
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'Email Success!';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Script (Beta)");


  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 3; // Number of rows to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];    // First column
    var message = row[1];         // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];       // Third column


    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates

      var subject = '[Auto] The Process Has Not Yet Been Started';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

[Doc Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15tHI8ygncIwNVwtaJjhrL6uK4Y_2vuIpwnJ-cGmoBr8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your range dynamic, you could use [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow), which returns the position of the last row with content.

Assuming that function `sendEmails2` is the one your using for this, you would just have to modify the variable `numRows`. You would have to change this line:

```js
var numRows = 3; // Number of rows to process
```

To this one:

```js
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1;
```

#### Reference:

- [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Nope. That's not working. Now the mail is also not getting sent

Comment: @ShabutheenB I tested this before posting my answer and I just tested it now. It is sending the emails correctly. If you change the line I told you and run the `sendEmails2` function from the file `AU_test.gs`, it will send the emails correctly (of course, only if there are emails to send - if there are lines of content that don't have `Email Success!` in `Email Status`). Also make sure that this variable is declared in the script: `var EMAIL_SENT = 'Email Success!';`. Follow exactly these steps and try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's working now. I don't know where it went wrong but the end of the script run the error is coming up as Failed to send an email: no recipient (line 33, file "script"). How do I end the loop properly and also sending myself the log as my report for every run. Any suggestions

Comment: @ShabutheenB you avoid this error, you have to make sure that all rows with content in `Script (Beta)` have valid email addresses in column A, and not empty cells. Also, I don't know what you mean by `How do I end the loop properly and also sending myself the log as my report for every run`. As it is written, the messages will send what is right now in column B as mail body.

Comment: Is there any way to send it as table using google script?

Comment: @ShabutheenB if you want your email to contain HTML tables, you can use [MailApp.sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage), provide the parameter `htmlBody`, and provide a [table element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) in this body.